# Parsing multi-line, multi-column text response with jersey/apache REST client

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to hit a REST end-point that returns a multi-line, multi-column response, such as:

```
A1   B1    C1
A2   B2    C2
A3   B3    C3
...
...
```

I'm currently using jersey-client to hit this endpoint and trying to look for the neatest way to parse this response. Here, each line would represent a bean, say `MyBean` and each column on that would represent a property in that bean. The order of values in the response is always fixed.

I can get the response back as a long String, split it at line-feeds and tabs to get individual values.

However, I would like to know if there is a way where I can get the results as a `List<String>`, where each element in the `List` would represent a line of the response. I can then split it on `\t` to get individual values.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    WebResource resource = client.resource(NETSPEAK_URL)
                 .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                 .get(new GenericType<List<String>>(){});
```

But this leads to the following exception:

```
    A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, 
    and Java type java.util.List<java.lang.String>, 
    and MIME media type text/plain; charset=UTF-8 was not found
```

If I be even greedier, I would like to know if I can get the individual column values mapped to the properties of my bean, `MyBean`. I've considered creating a wrapper around `MyBean`, to have a list of `MyBean`s, but then how would I annotate it to assist parsing? That would have made sense for an xml/json response. But this is plain text.

Is it possible to somehow tell jersey-client about the parsing of this text/plain response? If this is achievable through Apache HTTP client, I'm ready to move.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to implement a class representing your list of beans, say `class BeanList extends List<Bean>`, and implement a `MessageBodyReader<BeanList>` (see http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) to teach jersey how to read a string as a `BeanList`.

Then you can use `BeanList.class` instead of `List<String>` as argument to the `get` call.